# Bootstrap - how to eliminate the margin of the header image

Tags: css, position

I guess it's really basic, but I haven't found an answer here. I just use the class `.navbar-brand img` to change the width of my logo image and it works fine, but for some reason the image has margin from the top and it's not positioned correctly. I try to eliminate the margin with `margin-top:0` or `padding-top:0` and it doesn't change anything.

How can I reposition it?

Thanks in advance, and hope it's not a repost

Comment: You need to post your code. Please read [mcve]

Comment: Ok. In my index.html:

Comment: <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

Comment: I can't indent the code for some reason I'm sorry. But it's just the basic html to make the logo appear.

Comment: No, don't put your code in a comment, update your question and properly format it please.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap v4 has spacing utitlity classes for making margin and padding 0 for all sides and for each sides

Add `m-0` class for margin:0 ,

Add `mt-0` class for margin-top:0

**...**

Similarly for padding

Add `p-0` class for padding:0 ,

Add `pt-0` class for padding-top:0

More info [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)